# How to rewrite CodePen JS file to React application and add dependencies based on the External Scripts

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I want to demonstrate the FilePond module in a React application by uploading simple file. I have CodePen sample:

https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/WXavEx

If you go to Settings and then JavaScript tab, you can find many External Scripts/Pen added on this CodePen project. My question is how we can re-write this JS file below to React file and how do we identify the dependencies to be installed?

```
/*
We want to preview images, so we need to register the Image Preview plugin
*/
FilePond.registerPlugin(

    // encodes the file as base64 data
  FilePondPluginFileEncode,

    // validates the size of the file
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,

    // corrects mobile image orientation
    FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,

    // previews dropped images
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);

// Select the file input and use create() to turn it into a pond
FilePond.create(
    document.querySelector('input')
);
```

Comment: When you say "how to identify the dependencies to be installed", do you mean like "what should I npm install into a React project to make this work"?

Comment: You can likely just use this module instead: https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond

Comment: @Cassidy - Yes, that's exactly I am looking for..

Comment: great, I'll make it an answer for your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use this module for React and FilePond!

[github.com/pqina/react-filepond](http://github.com/pqina/react-filepond)